# Kotlin Back-Tick escaping in method names: How does it work?

Tags: java, gradle, junit, jvm, kotlin

In Kotlin, it's possible to name a method using back-ticks like this:

```
fun `i am a test method`(){
   Assert.assertEquals("x", "x")
}
```

The *compiler* generates a method with underscores instead of blanks: "i_am_a_test_method", which seems reasonable as the JVM does *not permit* methods with blanks afaik. How can **Junit** and/or **Gradle** report these tests with the back-ticked name though?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In a [Java method descriptor](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se7/html/jvms-4.html#jvms-4.3), several characters have a special meaning, namely `[` `(` `)` `/` and `;`. The space doesn't have any special meaning, and therefore it can be used directly in a method name; that's exactly what the compiler does. The spaces are not converted to underscores.

Comment: A Java decompiler tries to produce valid Java source code from a given class file. In a Java source file, there is no way to represent spaces in a method name, so the decompiler replaces them with underscores. To understand how the Kotlin compiler really works, you need to look at the bytecode, not at the decompiler output.

Comment: javap shows spaces in method names, it produces `public final void testing LookupCodes();` for `fun \`testing LookupCodes\`()`

Comment: Is there any way to call these methods from java without using reflection?

Comment: @herman No, such methods can only be called through reflection.